# Sugarcrm relationship between custom modules

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

i'm new with sugar crm i'm using Sugar CE 6.5.16 with MySQL and IIS7 windows.
i created two modules, deploy them, add custom fields and layouts. evrything works fine.In Order to get a detailed view for the primary module with a subpanel listing the items from the second module being related to it..i made a one-to-many relationship between these two modules. the problem is when clicking on the primary module elemants nothing shows up (there is no detail view or anything else) the secondary module did show a new field to relate items to it and the details view is fine.
evrything was done via studio and module builder. no file editing was made.
i'm thinking the issue is in this file: \custom\modules\Primary_module\Ext\layoutdefs\layoutdefs.exe.php :

```
<?php 
//WARNING: The contents of this file are auto-generated
// created: 2014-04-17 15:19:10
$layout_defs["plt01_Chassis"]["subpanel_setup"]['plt01_chassis_plt01_cartes_1'] =array   (
'order' => 100,
'module' => 'plt01_Cartes',
'subpanel_name' => 'default',
'sort_order' => 'asc',
'sort_by' => 'id',
'title_key' => 'LBL_PLT01_CHASSIS_PLT01_CARTES_1_FROM_PLT01_CARTES_TITLE',
'get_subpanel_data' => 'plt01_chassis_plt01_cartes_1',
'top_buttons' => 
array (
0 => 
array (
  'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopButtonQuickCreate',
),
1 => 
array (
  'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton',
  'mode' => 'MultiSelect',
),
),
);
//auto-generated file DO NOT EDIT
$layout_defs['plt01_Chassis']['subpanel_setup']['plt01_chassis_plt01_cartes_1']['override_subpanel_name'] = 'plt01_Chassis_subpanel_plt01_chassis_plt01_cartes_1';
?>
```

because when i delete the content the detailed view appear but no subpanels...any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed guys..problem was the French language package...i logged in using english and the custom modules relationship works and the detailed view is appearing with the subpanels!!
if someone has the same issue...try this and see if it works.
Best Regards